Automatically generating controllers with OData support for some Entity Framework models
I have some Entity Framework models and their associated context, I want to automatically create controllers for each model with OData support in my ASP.NET Core Web API.
It seems like "new Scaffolded Item" in Visual Studio does it one by one which makes it tedious. Is there any tool to automatically perform this operation for all models?
